# Android BroadcastReceiver not triggered

Tags: android, android-emulator, broadcastreceiver, android-service

there are a lot of questions related to this topic. but I cannot get it to run on my Device 4.2.1 on the emulator 5.0 it is working fine.:

here the Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.bootService"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <receiver
        android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:label="MyBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="1001" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".PingService" >
    </service>
    <service android:name=".UpdateService" >
    </service>

    <receiver android:name=".OnBootReceiver" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="1001" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
</manifest>
```

I tried it with 2 receivers: none of them working. 
Here one of the receivers that should write a logfile to SD, which is working fine from the Launcher Activity:

```
 public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
// Restart service every 30 seconds
private static final long REPEAT_TIME = 1000 * 10;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.e("MyBroadcastReceiver", "BroadcastReceiver");
    appendLog("MyBroadcastReceiver   BroadcastReceiver \n");
    AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
    PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);

    service.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            cal.getTimeInMillis(), REPEAT_TIME, pending);

    Log.wtf("MyBroadcastReceiver", "Alarm went off");



}

public static void appendLog(String text) {
    File logFile = new File("sdcard/logfile.txt");
    if (!logFile.exists()) {
        try {
            logFile.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        // BufferedWriter for performance, true to set append to file flag
        BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile,
                true));
        buf.append(text);
        buf.newLine();
        buf.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I cannot see the error. Anyone does?
PS the app is started once, so this: http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/05/boot-completed-regression.html is covered.

thanks,

Comment: BOOT_COMPLETED this means, when you device get restarted and get ready to use. I hope you understand what it means.

Comment: @MurtazaHussain of course. The above code should let a logfile on the sd card after mobile has finished booting.

Comment: However it is not working.

Comment: I just found out that on the emulator it is working and on my mobile not.

Comment: Which os your devices has?

Comment: @MurtazaHussain the mobile runs 4.2.1 and the emulator 5.0

Comment: I triggered the broadcast by restarting device and using sdb shell command. however the receiver is only active on the emulator

Comment: Maybe it is my device? That is not firing on boot completed? However other apps from the play store installed are starting services upon boot completed.

Comment: Try to remove priority tag

Comment: Thank you. But it didnt change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me long the key to the problem was in the manifest.xml

here the changes to got it run (only the receiver block):

```
 <receiver
        android:name="com.example.bootService.MyBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />

            <data
                android:path="com.example.bootService"
                android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>
```

important was the

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

tag